# How do I get all the results not in a set?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im joining two tables and I want to then join a third but I want to get the result of the records that dont join. Dont really know what to use to do this. Can I search for nulls that appear outside the join or something?

Comment: Please provide the schema of all 3 tables with sample data with expected output. In general, I think you are looking for `EXISTS`.

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: +1 @OMGPonies - that's my goto resource for this question, which comes up a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best-performing way** to do this in general is to use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` - they are identical behind the scenes in SQL Server 2005+.

They are preferred over `LEFT JOIN...IS NULL` because they short circuit - as soon as the matching condition is found, that record is skipped.  `LEFT JOIN` loads the whole data set and relation, then eliminates records afterwards.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
<other joins>
WHERE a.ComparisonField NOT IN (SELECT RelationField FROM OtherTable)
```

or

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
<other joins>
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM OtherTable o
                 WHERE o.Relationfield = a.Comparisonfield)
```

Comment: Not sure why my question was closed as this is the answer I was looking for thanks!